# Sqlite One to Many Relationship

Tags: c#, list, generics, xamarin, sqlite-net

I'm currently making an app that needs to store and get data to and from a sqlite database. The two Nuget packages I'm currently using are `Sqlite PCL` and `SQLite-Net Extensions`.

```
[Table("patient")]
public class Patient
{
[PrimaryKey]
public string ID { get; set;}

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [OneToMany]
    public List<PatientVitals> PatientVitals { get; set; }
}

[Table("patientVitals")]
public class PatientVitals
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string VitalID {get;set;}

    public string Weight { get; set;}
    public string Height { get; set;}

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Patient))]
    public string SmartCardID {get;set;}
}
```

The whole thing is compiled fine, but when I try to run the simulator I'm getting this message:

> System.NotSupportedException has been thrown Don't know about
>   System.Collections.Generic.List1

I checked the SQLite-Net Extensions [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) and it does support List.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Doesn't work, getting the same message.Thanks though!

Comment: I thin there is a fix that they are working on ( or worked) to fix the the List<> issue. [link](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/pull-requests/12/support-ilist-instead-of-list-as-enclosed/diff#comment-8587796)

Answer (score 0):

Please add the primary key of Patient as Foreign key in table PatientVitals.

Comment: It's the public string SmartCardID.

Comment: You have to change 
`[ForeignKey(typeof(PatientItem))]`
to 
`[ForeignKey(typeof(Patien))]`

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, after some research, it turned out that I had to remove all of the SQLite related nudgets and re-install them into the project. In my case, since I need the SQLite-Net Extensions, I only need to put it in my project and any dependencies nudgets will also be installed along with SQL-Net Extensions.