# Xamarin (IOS Android UWP) with SQlite Use OneToMany

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, uwp, one-to-many

My setup is the following. I'm developing a cross plateform Xamarin solution on IOS Android and UWP, in addition of that I want to use SQlite as a local database.

In order to use SQlite on UWP and the others I had to install the nuget packet (sqlite-net-pcl by Frank A. Krueger).

Everything works fine but for some reason I cant use the Attribute OneToMany. The solution seems to be to remove the SqlitePcl package https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48545/xamarin-forms-with-sqlite-one-to-many-relationship.

I am basically blocked because of those two constraints (UWP + OneToMany).

Has anyone ever encountered the same issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everything works fine but for some reason I cant use the Attribute OneToMany.

[SQLite-net PCL](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) package created by Frank A. Krueger is recommended in the Xamarin official document [Local Databases](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/). This package doesn't support `ForeignKey` and `OneToMany` attributes by default. If you want to obtain the  relationship you can query the database using the Query method of `SQLiteConnection`, for example:

```
return db.Query<Valuation> ("select * from Valuation where StockId = ?", stock.Id);
```

Details please reference [sqlite-net wiki](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/wiki/GettingStarted).

The code snippet of above [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081303/sqlite-one-to-many-relationship) contains `one-to-many` attrubute directly, which need the  [SQLite-Net Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) package. This package provides one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many, inverse and text-blobbed relationships on top of the sqlite-net library. This package published the nuget packages `2.0.0-alpha2` to support `sqlite-net-pcl to 1.2.0` according to the [commit info](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/commits/branch/master).

So you may need to use [`SQLite-net PCL 1.2.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/1.2.0) package combine with [`SQLite.Net Extensions-PCL 2.0.0-alpha2`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/2.0.0-alpha2) package to meet your requirements. If you need to use higher version of SQLite-net but no extension package matching you can create your own by reference the [extension source code](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/ffa73e87ab948c1dd3d584572bcbdab19d65a17a?at=master).

By the way, you may also try to use Entity Framework Core which also can set [relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships). Details please reference [this article](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95916/works-xamarin-forms-net-standard-entity-framework-core-for-sqlite-on-ios-android-uwp) and [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/8792).